# Cannot change keyboard layout with keyboard shortcut

Tags: release-freya, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I have a problem with switching elementaryOS Freya layout. Shortcut is default (Alt+Space), but when you press it - it opens menu window instead of changing layout. I though a good solution would be to change keyboard layout, however that does not seem an easy task.

I tried looking into System settings > Keyboard > Universal access - however there is no Next layout line.
I tried seeting it manually with commands like:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings switch-input-source "['Caps_Lock']"
```

Responds with:

```
No such key 'switch-input-source'
```

In dconf - after you navigate to gala.keybindings - there is no line for layouts whatsoever.

Ideas where to continue? Thanks in advance

Edit: it is a deal breaker for me since it really plunges my productivity (laptop does not have numpad and I am frequently change layouts)

Comment: Do have more than one keyboard layout installed? I do not know if there is the option when only one layout is installed...

Comment: yes there are two keyboard layouts currently present.
Edit: I can change layout with mouse - everything works great

Comment: edit2: I want to mention that I still cannot change it with keyboard which makes using elementaryOS hard. (since I need to change layout frequently)

Comment: Did you change any other keys in the "keybindings scheme"? If not you can try to reset all the entries with `gsettings reset-recursively org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings`. Maybe after that you get the key "switch-input-source" back and you can change it the "normal way".

Comment: I didn't change any other shortcuts, however I tried resetting with the command you suggested. Still no switch input source.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the correct scheme where to find the `switch-input` key is:
`org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings`

I successfully changed the keyboard input keybinding with the following command:
 `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Super>f']"`

Now, if I press Super+F it changes my keyboard layout.

Comment: Cannot check if answer is valid. Switched to OS X